# Specify test folder in Jenks

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to build my project, and AgitarOne tool to generate my JUnit test cases for my classes.  However, when I build my project in Jenkins, it does not use the AgitarOne tests.  Is there a way to configure jenkins to look at a test folder other than what is in src/test?

Comment: What tasks does Jenkins perform for your build?  Do you have a build automation tool, like maven or gradle?  If so, that's what you want to configure to look at an alternative test folder.

Comment: @BurntCornMuffin We use Maven to build our project.  So from what I did a quick search on, adding `build-helper-maven-plugin` in my pom.xml file can allow me to specify which test resource to use?  Or do I have to set it in my Maven goals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change your test directory to a non-standard location, you'll need to change the testSourceDirectory on your pom (the answer to [How to run UnitTests in maven which is in src/test-integration/java folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784423/how-to-run-unittests-in-maven-which-is-in-src-test-integration-java-folder) has a very good explanation of this, as well as buildhelper usage to achieve your goals).